# How to map data from database with Griffin-Framework Data-Mapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, mapper

I have two tables:
User and UserType:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UserTypeId] [int] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserType](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

My model classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
public class UserType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    U.Id
    , U.Name
    , UT.Id AS [UserTypeId]
    , UT.Name AS [UserTypeName]
FROM dbo.User AS F 
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserType AS UT ON U.UserTypeId = UT.Id
ORDER BY U.Id
```

And my mapper class:

```
public class UserMapper : CrudEntityMapper<User>
{
    public UserMapper() : base("User")
    {
        Property(x => x.UserType)
            .ColumnName("UserTypeId")
            .ToPropertyValue((x) => new UserType { Id = (int)x });
        Property(x => x.UserType)
            .ColumnName("UserTypeName")
            .ToPropertyValue((x) => new UserType { Name = (string)x });
    }
}
```

when i try to execute command i get list of users without userType.Id (Id always = 0). I need to fill with data my `User` and child `UserType` classes.

Please show me what i'm doing wrong.

```
cmd.ToList<User>();
```

PS. im using [Griffin.Framework](https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Framework/tree/master/src/Griffin.Framework) for mapping

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Griffin per se, but it's clear the issue is the fact that you have two separate mappings for `UserType`.  Each mapping is creating a brand new object that overwrites the `UserType` member on your `User` object.  Depending on which column gets mapped first, you'll always get a `UserType` object that has only one property set.

Looking at the source for [FluentPropertyMapping](https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Framework/blob/master/src/Griffin.Framework/Griffin.Core/Data/Mapper/FluentPropertyMapping.cs), there does not appear to be an option to map multiple columns down to one.  A potential workaround, which depends on support for mapping nested properties:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        UserType = new UserType();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

and in your mapping:

```
public class UserMapper : CrudEntityMapper<User>
{
    public UserMapper() : base("User")
    {
        Property(x => x.UserType.Id)
            .ColumnName("UserTypeId");
        Property(x => x.UserType.Name)
            .ColumnName("UserTypeName");
    }
}
```